# How to refresh Swift UIViewController from Delegate callback

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm a noob.  I have some programming experience, but am new to Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2.

I've been taking tutorials and reading.  I've implemented one of the many Music Player examples to be found.  I've expanded it to display song metatdata.  This works fine.

I've implemented the AVAudioPlayerDelegate audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying() function. In this function, I grab the next songs metadata, set the view variables, and play the song.  The song plays, but the old song metadata remains.

How do I refresh the view with my new metadata?

*I apologize in advance for such a simple question.  I have search extensively for an answer and either haven't understood or seems not applicable.  Be kind, I'm old and fragile.*

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var currentSongArtwork: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentSongTitle: UILabel!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playSong()
    }

    func playSong() {
        extractSongMetaData()
        currentSongTitle.text = extractedSongTitle
        currentSongArtwork = extractedSongArtwork

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[currentSongIndex], ofType: ".m4a")
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        // Increment currentSongIndex

        playSong()
      }
}
```

Comment: try doing this in your audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
DispatchQueue.main.async
      {
        playsong()
      }

Comment: What does the `extractSongMetadata` function do? If you are extracting the metadata asynchronously, then the new data would not have been loaded by the time the following two lines are called.

Comment: New to stackoverflow.  if this is not the correct area to respond to a question in response to my post, please advise. Christian, I added the code the DispatchQueue that you suggested.  It works, but is EXTREMELY slow.  When clicking my NEXT button the UI updates immediately and the song begins playing.  In the audioPlayerDidFinishing() method, the song begins playing immediately, but the UI takes 50 seconds in Xcode to be updated!  FYI.  My machine is plenty beefy.

Comment: Jsdodgers, no the data is extracted in the main thread...not asynchronously. 'code'         let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: songsURL[currentSongIndex])
        let metadataList = playerItem.asset.commonMetadata

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call the playSong inside the UI thread for it to refresh properly.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    // Increment currentSongIndex

    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        playSong()
    }
}
```